# How do i create multiple shapes that are an equal distance apart using pygame?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Under #Trees i had written a for loop. The first loop works fine, x = 0.

The second loop, however, although x = 300, the shape doesn't move from its original spot.

What this is supposed to do is change the x coordinates of my shape after the 2nd "for loop" is finished creating the leaves on my tree.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode([640,600])

# color reference
white = (255,245,238)
blue = (65,105,225)
green = (154,205,50)
grey = (105,105,105)
lightblue = (176,196,222)
brown = (93, 64, 55)
darkgreen = (0, 121, 107)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    # Sky
    window.fill((135,206,250))
    # Pond
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (blue), Rect((0,510),(640,100)))
    # House base
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (white), Rect((100,310),(200,190)))
    # Grass
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (green), Rect((0,500),(440,100)))
    # Windowsill
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (grey), Rect((200,420),(80,10)))
    # Window/Door
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (lightblue), Rect((206,360),(70,60)))
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (lightblue), Rect((115,410),(70,90)))
    # Doorknob
    pygame.draw.circle(window, (grey), (125, 459), 5, 0)
    # Roof
    pygame.draw.polygon (window, (grey), ((100,310),(203,260),(299,310)))
    # Trees
    for trees in range(3):
        y = 0
        x = 0
        pygame.draw.rect (window, (brown), Rect((40 + x,470),(20,30)))
        for leaves in range(3):
            pygame.draw.polygon (window, (darkgreen), ((10 + x,470 - y),(50 + x,410 - y),(90 + x,470 - y)))
            y = y + 40
            if leaves == 2:
                x = x + 300


    pygame.display.flip()
```

My goal is to have a tree on both sides of the house, using a for loop.
A little help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work

```
# Trees
y = 0
x = 0
for trees in range(2):
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (brown), Rect((40 + x,470),(20,30)))
    for leaves in range(3):
        pygame.draw.polygon (window, (darkgreen), ((10 + x,470 - y),(50 + x,410 - y),(90 + x,470 - y)))
        y = y + 40
        if leaves == 2:
            x = x + 300
            y = y - 120
```

The for loop kept changing the x and y values back to zero, so i set the range of the leaves back to 3 and moved the x and y accumulator variables above the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need the `y` and `x` variables above the for loops, since you can pass an optional "step" argument to `range`. So for example `list(range(0, 81, 40))` gives you `[0, 40, 80]`.

```
for x in range(0, 301, 300):
    pygame.draw.rect (window, (brown), Rect((40 + x,470),(20,30)))
    for y in range(0, 81, 40):
        pygame.draw.polygon(
            window, darkgreen,
            ((10+x, 470-y), (50+x, 410-y), (90+x, 470-y)))
```